# Windows from HDD to SSD via clone

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-server-2012

Is there an easy way to enable all the SSD features for Windows Server 2012 R2?

I would like to avoid having to do a reinstall and just clone for time sakes.

I've read it is best to do a fresh install so all the SSD features are enabled by default. Is there a quick way to enable them all without doing a reinstall?

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of one of these features you feel can't be simply enabled?

Comment: Not really that. More in terms of how much time is involved to manually enable the features. Let me rephrase the question :)